# Assets Class not exported to Frame 2

Tags: actionscript-3, preloader, starling-framework

I am using Flash IDE i have set Export Classes to frame 2 . I have an Assets Class which have Assets Embedded. This is the code on my first frame

```
stop();
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS , onProgress);
function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
{
    // to animate preloader
    ldrBar.width = (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded / this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal) * 200;

    // to go to frame 2 when loading done
    if (this.loaderInfo.bytesLoaded == this.loaderInfo.bytesTotal)
    {
        gotoAndStop(2);
    }
}
```

On frame two I have

```
import Main;
addChild(new Main());
stop();
```

When i Test the movie bandwidth Profiler shows 2MB on frame 1 and some KB  on frame 2 although i have set the Option Export Class in frame 2
This approached worked for me in my previous projects (non-starling) but it is not working now

Comment: Is Main the assets class?

Comment: @ozmachine No I have created a separate class for **assets**.I n which i used Embed meta tags and i have some function like **getTexture** and **getAtlas** .

Comment: If Main has references to the assets class, then main may need to be exported on frame 2 as well.

Comment: @ozmachine i said earlier that I have set the option in**Actionscript settings** which says **Export classes in Frame** to frame 2

Comment: Do you have any linked symbols in your library, and in their preferences is "export in the first frame" unchecked?

Comment: @ozmachine My library is empty because in order to create a class i dont use **Create new symbol options** I just go to **File>New>Actionscript Class**.Therefore they are not shown up in the library